# rename(): Cannot rename a file across wrapper types

Tags: php, image, image-uploading

When i upload image it gives me following error:

> rename(): Cannot rename a file across wrapper types

here what i have done:

```
rename($sourcePath, $destinationPath)
```

in above variable it contains path of image including image name

can anyone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `$sourcePath`... If I'm not mistaken, your `$sourcePath` contains `http://`, try removing that and replace it with a local path instead.

For example, if you're current `$sourcePath` is:

```
http://domain.com/uploads/image.jpg
```

Replace it with:

```
/uploads/image.jpg
```